# TeXLive 2020: How to deal with tikz-berge and tikz-kiviat packages that were removed from CTAN

Tags: texlive, mactex, tkz-kiviat, tkz-berge

The MWE below works fine with TeXLive 2019 and produces:

[image]

But with TexLive 2020 version (MacTeX) I get

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tikz-berge.sty` not found
! LaTeX Error: File `tikz-kiviat` not found
```

It seems as if these packages are no longer part of the TeXLive distribution and are marked on CTAN as having "*been taken temporarily out of circulation to give the author time to investigate some problems*.".

As my original question as to what happened to these pacakges was addressed in the comments (now documented in the text of this question), I am wondering what is the best way to proceed if someone needs the versions of these pacakges that were available before (and worked fine, at least for some cases that I know of).

My solution as of now is that I have the following directoes in my local tree:

```
texmf-local/tex/latex/tkz-berge
texmf-local/tex/latex/tkz-graph
texmf-local/tex/latex/tkz-kiviat
```

which contain the versions of the .sty from the TeXLive2019 release.   This seems to be working as of now, but leads me to the following questions:

1. How do I automate the detection of a new version of this, should it be available in a future release.
2. The logic for removing a package that has been there for many years escapes me, especially since it was provding some working functioality. If anyone can elaboarate on this that would be useful to know.

### Reference:

The code for the diagrams is taken directly from

- [How to color Petersen Graph using tkz-berge?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142284/4301)
- [How to draw Kiviat Diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10060/4301)

The status of the packages is noted at

- [CTAN: tkz-berge](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-berge)
- [CTAN: tkz-kiviat](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-kiviat)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage} 
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{white}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10060/4301
\tkzKiviatDiagram[scale=0.75,label distance=.25cm,
        radial  = 5,
        gap     = 1,  
        lattice = 5]{McCabe,LOC,Live Variables,Halstead N,Variablenspanne}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue,mark=none,
               fill=blue!20,opacity=.5](3,3.5,3,3.5,3)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=darkgray,
               fill=green!20,opacity=.5](0.5,1,0.5,0.75,1) 
\tkzKiviatLine[ultra thick,mark=ball,
                 mark size=4pt,color =Maroon](2,3.75,1,1.5,2)    
\tkzKiviatGrad[prefix=,unity=100,suffix=\ \texteuro](1)  
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90, scale=0.5]%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142284/4301
\GraphInit[vstyle=Art]
\grPetersen[RA=5, RB=3]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: According to https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-berge `tkz-berge` "has been taken temporarily out of circulation to give the author time to investigate some problems." Same for `tkz-kiviat`: https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-kiviat

Comment: If you need the package, you can probably download it directly from CTAN and just drop the `.sty` files where LaTeX can find it.

Comment: @moewe: Seems strange to do that to a package that has been around for many years and has significant functionality that seems to work. Yeah, I can do that but them have to remember to use that only for TeXLive2020 and every year check if it is now availalble. Any idea where the list of "some problems" is stored?

Comment: I don't know about the details, but there was a thread on the TeX live mailing list that basically said the same thing https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-March/045014.html

Comment: @moewe: Thanks for your insight. Have updated the question to include those details and adjusted it so that it is more useful (well at least useful to me).

Comment: How about cloning the repositories from github in your local `texmf`?
https://github.com/tkz-sty

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin: I don't necessarily want development versions. Only want them when they are part of CTAN packages and updated as part of via normal TeXLive Utility.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: I did not know my post came across like I was trying to put pressure on the author, so thank you for pointing that out.  That was absolutely _not_ the intent. I appreciate the packages, and like I said they work fine, at least for the small test cases where I have used them.  But still was schocking to me that packages were removed after so many years. My main question still is how to best modify things now so that when and if new versions are released that I can detect it as part of my normal `pfdlatex`ing.